# How to undo typo `set -ovi`?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, set

I wanted to execute `set -o vi`, but instead I did `set -ovi`.

Now when I checking `set -o` I see extra weird options such as:

```
$ set -o
set -o
...
update_terminal_cwd;
```

and as result, `update_terminal_cwd;` is printed on each command.

How do I undo my typo without restarting shell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you did `set -ovi` then repeat as `set +ovi` the effect of one will be reversed by the other.

What you actually did was activate the verbose option `set -o v` which shows history (if set) as well.

The most important values set are printed by `echo "$-"`, which is usually just `himBH` in interactive shells.

A longer list of values is printed either by `set -o` or `set +o`. The former will print an human readable description of values set (on) or unset (off). The later will print an almost complete list that could be executed back to restore `set` state.

With either `set -o` or `set +o` list check the state of verbose and unset 
it with either of this commands:

```
set +o verbose
set +o v
```

Yes, `+` means unset (off), weird, I understand.

Answer (score 4):

`set +v`

(In the general case, if `set -<char>` turned an option on, `set +<char>` will turn it off.)

Answer (score 1):

Or inspect the differences via something like (on the possibly rash assumption that options are not passed along like environment variables are):

```
set -o > now
bash -ic 'set -o' > default
diff default now
```

Comment: Sorry, but the settings of a non-interactive shell are usually different of an interactive shell. Get into a new shell as `$ bash` create the file then: `set -o > default`, exit the shell `$ exit` and then compare.